# where are the poles in the product of zeta functions, and where are their residues?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

I am trying to find the poles an residues of an expression of the form

$$\left(\sum_i \zeta(m_i) \right)^2$$

where $m_i\in \mathcal{M}$ some set of integers including 1. Now I know that on the we only have a single simple pole at 1, so I would imagine that the square I have above has both simple poles arising from

$$\zeta(1)\sum_{m_i \neq1} \zeta(m_i) $$

with residue $\sum_{m_i \neq1} \zeta(m_i)$ as well as a second order pole from $\zeta(1)\zeta(1)$.

On the other hand

$$\left(\sum_i \zeta(m_i) \right)^2  =   \left(\sum_i\sum_n n^{-m_i} \right)^2 = \sum_{i,j}\sum_n n^{-m_i-m_j} = \sum_{i,j}\zeta(m_i+m_j) = \sum_i p^2_{\mathcal{M}} (m_i)\zeta(m_i)$$

where $p^2_{\mathcal{M}} (m_i)$ is the number of solutions to $m+n = m_i$ with $m,n \in \mathcal{M}$. In any case this only has a simple pole at $m_i=1$ with residue $p^2_{\mathcal{M}} (1)$. .

I dont see why these two should be equivalent (in fact, barring some mathemagic, I cant see how these are), but I also dont see which of these is correct.

Comment: Note that the $\zeta(s)^2$ term will also contribute to the residue at $s=1$ (it contributes $2\gamma$ as it turns out, where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the calculation is in the second equality. You correctly turned the index $i$ inside the square into two indices $i,j$ when expanding the square out, but you forgot to do the same with the single index $n$—it should become two indices $k,n$ after squaring out. (Note that if this calculation were correct, it would show in particular the incorrect identity $\zeta(s)^2=\zeta(2s)$.)